# Constructing a sequence in the Ffnctional space $C^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am studying Partial Differential Equations. In my teacher's lecture notes, he wrote:

> We define $\varphi(y) = |y|1_{y<0}$. Although $\varphi(y)$ does not belong to $C^2(\mathbb{R})$, we can construct a sequence $(\varphi_n)$ such that $\varphi_n$ belongs  to $C^2(\mathbb{R})$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$  and $\lim \varphi_n =\varphi$, $\lim \varphi_n' =\varphi'$.

Can you help me to explain this statement? In other words, **how** can one construct the sequence $\varphi_n$?

Comment: Which part of the statement do you not understand?

Comment: How to construct a sequence like that?

Answer (score 0):

The first function outputs 0 if $y\geq 0$ (That's from the indicator function part) and otherwise returns $|y|$, which in this case is the same as $-y$ since its on negatives. In other words, it is a union of two rays,  $y=-x$ on the negatives and $y=0$ on the positives and thus is not even differentiable at $0$, let alone $C^2$.  The idea is we can make a sequence of functions that ARE $C^2$ such that they get closer and closer to this behavior,  by turning that sharp corner into smaller and smaller curves.  The second equation only makes sense for $y\neq 0$, since the original function is not differentiable at 0

Comment: I understood the idea but i don't know how to make a sequence like that. Can you give me an example of a sequence which follows the statement?

Comment: I haven't worked with them myself, but what you want to look into are mollifiers.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier